# Can an eCommerce site from one domain appear under another domain?

Tags: domains, redirects, prestashop

I have a new client, Business A, who has a website already set up on a domain they have purchased: `businessa.com`. They wish in collaboration with another company, Business B, to sell products using an unused PrestaShop belonging to Business B on `businessb.com` - but under the name of Business A. I believe they are splitting costs and profits in some way, so the reason is legitimate.

They wish the user to be at `businessa.com`, click a link to the shop which actually goes to `businessb.com`, but still displays as `businessa.com` throughout the shopping experience.

This isn't something I've looked at before and have not had much luck Googling it. What is the best method to achieve this so that search engines will not perceive it as something underhanded and no other potential problems arise?

Comment: What issue do you see with SSL? SSL doesn't care what business' logo shows on the page, unless I'm missing something. And what is the perceived benefit of selling at Business B's domain? Is it just so that they don't have to pay for Prestashop?

Comment: This is most often referred to as [domain masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_masking), and generally isn't a good idea for eCommerce sites to do. I'd advise your clients to maintain the separate domains, but use consistent branding and design themes between the two instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying Maximillian. I thought that if the SSL is associated with businessb.com, but the address is showing as businessa.com, won't the SSL show as not matching? I believe that they are collaborating with Business A and sharing profits, I don't think it's a desire to shirk anything.

Comment: Thank you Dan, that's pretty much what I thought might be the case. Your advice is very much appreciated.